# Android Bluetooth Notification

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Bluetooth application in android.Once connection is made between two devices i am sending data between two devices. My problem is whenever either of the devices Bluetooth is turned off i want that to be notified to other device and want to print a toast message stating that "Other device Bluetooth is turned off".How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the bluetooth connection (listening to Broadcast action : ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) and notify that the connection has gone. Dropping of connection does not necessarily mean it is powered off , but it is surely a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

The following link can be useful to you

- [notification if the Bluetooth is turned off in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388609/notification-if-the-bluetooth-is-turned-off-in-android-app)

Comment: That's not the exact answer i am looking for.When two devices are connected and when Bluetooth is turned off in one device, i want that to be notified to another device.