# Bluetooth low energy, background check

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to create a BLE mesh in Java for a University project, but it's getting harder than expected. First of all, the documentation given in Android Developers is too general and doesn't explain how to implement the methods and services, it just describes them a little. Then there is actually little information about this theme on the internet, and most of it is outdated, so after you make yourself an idea of how to start, you'll have to deal with tons of problems of compatibility and permission check.
For example now i´m trying to make a new thread to check in background the buetooth state, so that it sets the position of a switch, but there's nobody posting about that, and for now my application just close when initialice don´t know why.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BLECommunication{
    ...
    //private Thread checkBT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ...
    checkBT = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switchMaterial.setChecked(bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());
             }
```

Comment: This one is a good tutorial series about BLE for Android: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02. I don't think you actually need to use a new thread. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388609/notification-if-the-bluetooth-is-turned-off-in-android-app)

Comment: Oh I just read about you wanting to use BLE mesh. The tutorial I sent you is not about meshes but still a good starting point. What hardware are you using to build your mesh?

Comment: I would like to create an android app so that any android device with it installed coud be part of it.

Comment: So the mesh will consist of only android phones? I believe Android does not offer a native BLE mesh implementation as of now. I only used BLE meshes on different microcontrollers, where the phone simply connected to one device via BLE. There are some libraries available (like [this one](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stblemesh.html) ) but I'm not sure if it is possible to put the phone itself inside the mesh. Maybe this is a good starting point for you

Comment: Actually I wanted to create an application that would do exactly what that app is doing, but also implementing an internet gateway throught which any phone in the mesh could route some simple data, that's why i would like to make from the botton to above. Thank you anyway for you help.